# Assigning static const within a class and outside, why the difference?

Tags: c++, static, constants

This is so wierd, i am coding a pixel manipulation library in C++. So i want to have a class filled with color presets. Color is a class with a struct that looks like:

```
Color(int r, int g, int b, int a)
```

And if i declare it outside of any classes as:

```
static const Color COL_BLACK = Color(0, 0, 0, 255);
```

That shows no error in Visual Studio Code. But however when i structure like this:

```
class Colors {
public:
  static const Color Black = Color(0, 0, 0, 255);
};
```

The equal sign has a red squiggly line under it, but when i hover my mouse over it doesn't tell me what is wrong. What is wrong?

Note that i want it to be called like so:

```
Color newCol = Colors::Black;
```

Comment: Try `static inline const Color Black = Color(0, 0, 0, 255);` for the static member in `Colors`. ;-)

Comment: `static` members in a `class` declaration are a potential violation of the One Definition Rule (ODR) because the class declaration (in a header) could be repeated. In older standards, it was necessary to move the definition of static members into one translation unit (a `.cpp` file). Since recent standards (I believe C++17), an alternative option is the `static inline` (with the requirement that the `static inline`d hast to be equal at every time when its seen by the compiler again).

Comment: Though, a static definition of a global variable in a header is not that clever as well. Each time the header is seen, a new symbol will be generated... This symbol is exclusively visible in the corresponding object file but it still appears to be a waste (to me).

Answer (score 1):

Since C++ 17 you can simply use `inline` like in the following:

```
#include <iostream>

class Color
{
public:
    Color(int r, int g, int b, int a)
        : 
        r{ r },
        g{ g },
        b{ b },
        a{ a }
    {
    }

    int r, g, b, a;
};

class Colors 
{
public:
    inline static const Color Black = Color(0, 0, 0, 255);
};

int main()
{
    Color c = Colors::Black;
    std::cout << c.r << "," << c.g << "," << c.b << "," << c.a << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read up a little on static initialization. In the meantime, in this case you could define `Color` with a `constexpr` ctor, like this:

```
struct Color
{
  const unsigned int r;
  const unsigned int g;
  const unsigned int b;
  const unsigned int a;

  constexpr Color( const unsigned int r, const unsigned int g, const unsigned int b, const unsigned int a ) : r(r), g(g), b(b), a(a)
  {}
};
```

And then you would initialize `Colors` like this:

```
class Colors
{
  public:
    static constexpr Color Black = Color(0, 0, 0, 255);
};
```